# Banned from Ubuntu forums for spam. Could my Ubuntu have a virus?

Tags: viruses, ubuntu-forums

My IP address has been banned from the Ubuntu forums for spam but I have no knowledge of the spam or what could be happening. I have been in touch with the admins there but they refuse to help basically saying "We will un-ban you when you stop the spam." Since I don't know what is happening it feels to me like a security problem or maybe a virus on my Ubuntu machine is sending spam? I know people say that Ubuntu is virus proof but could this be an exception?

Comment: Dynamically assigned ip address?

Comment: Yes, I think it probably would be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been explained to you in multiple emails.

We do not blacklist IP addresses for single spam posts. We block IP addresses for sustained spam over days or more often weeks.

If we unblock your IP, you will post once or twice on the forums, then the spam will start, and we will then have to block the IP again.

So the solution is to either :

1. Ask you to stop spamming the forums. You say you are not and I believe you. So ...
2. You will have to wait until the party or parties responsible stop spamming the forums. We review banned IP addresses from time to time and will reverse the ban when the spam stops.

In the mean time you will have to use other support methods such as Ask Ubuntu, irc, or launchpad.

Why are you re-installing your OS ? I never advised that. How does that stop some third party from spamming the forums from your IP ?

You can lodge a complaint with your IP provider or you can contact the local authorities, but often they are disinterested. If you do identify the spammer, and get them to stop, I will unban your IP. Otherwise we wait them out. They usually go away eventually .... Sometimes they come back and are re-banned. In the case of your IP, with the previous history, it is likely to remain banned for some time.

We are blocking an 'block' of IPs - so in other words, because of the way your ISP gives you an IP address, someone on your block of IPs (aka, someone in your internet phone number area code) is spamming and so it's easier for us to block the entire block instead of just the specific spammer IP, since it changes every day.

Possibilities:

- Your WiFi is not secure.
- Your ISP is cycling IPs in a really odd fashion.

Comment: How does a 3rd party get access to your IP?  Just wait it out is a pretty unsatisfying answer.

Comment: it was suggested that he have a virus or some kind of program in his computar that was spamming the forums.

Comment: As DQdlM said, how can a third party be using my IP address? Should I be concerned about a greater problem than just not being able to view the forums?

Comment: @Chris I've edited based off of what bodhi said on IRC. That make sense?

Comment: Just like the OP , spamers use DHCP or change IP adresses. To stop spam we start with 11.22.33.1 , they then change to 11.22.33.2 , so with bad actors we then need to ban 11.22.33.* The OP is in a particularly nasty IP range, and is so collateral damage, and has a long wait. Collateral damage also occurs with public IP of large organizations or Universities. Please stop giving bad advice. The OP does not need to re-install his or her OS, no evidence to suggest a virus, trojan, intruder, cracker, etc although obviously we do not know.

Comment: @DQdlM Web admins do not like "wait it out" any more then you do. The problem is who is going to stop the spam ? IP providers ? The police? the CIA? TOR ? you ? the president ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen thanks for the additional info. must be very frustrating

Comment: We are going to review our IP ban list on the Forums. As put by another staff "It's going to be quite a job, reviewing the list we have." so give us time. Due to issues stated above, I can not guarantee any particular IP range will not need to be banned for how long. We do try to minimize collateral damage.

Comment: I have changed my wifi password and enabled MAC address filtering as an extra layer of security. It didn't look like there were any unknown DHCP clients on my network though. My ISP is a little different to most so maybe that explains the cycling IPs in a really odd fasion posibility I don't know. But, this all became less about getting access to the ubuntu forums and more about a greater security problem which worried me. Maybe you should send out an email explaining the things that I have only discovered by asking here when you block people.

Comment: One more thing you can do. As it is a range of IP addresses, not yours specifically, you can contact your ISP, explain the problem, and ask to be reassigned to a different IP address. A good ISP would not only do as you ask, but also ask for more information to locate the spammer.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that someone else has got your account details and is posting spam using them from other computers. So I would try changing your password to exclude that possibility and see if that causes the spam to stop.

Comment: Actually, it seems like his IP address is blocked. Not just the account.

Comment: Thats what I thought, I have even asked them to delete my accounts.

Answer (score 3):

I have done some further investigation and have been able to unblock the IP address you mentioned in your email - and have emailed you about this. You should be OK now, but we will need to monitor use of this IP address in case it is being spoofed by a persistent spambot.

Comment: Not exactly sure what 'spoofed by a persistent spambot' means OR if there is anything I can do to stop it other than taking the measures mentioned above such as securing my wifi better. Oh well, let's see what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Router**
If the problem is with your Ip. You could reset your router and get a new global Ip. that way you would get a new Ip that is not in use, and you wont spam. If now there isn't something wrong with your computer.

- Check your network, how many clients are connected?
- It could be that your wireless isn't secure enough, change the password, change the name and change the encryption type.
- Do you know who ownes the clients on your network?

**Not a Virus** 
[**it's not a virus.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus) a virus is a program that installs on your computer by itself, it's **really** unlikely that it's a virus.

**Trojan?**
[But it could be a trojan.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_%28computing%29) A program that you have installed and isn't what you think it is.

[this is ubuntu.com's offical antivirus page.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus) I hope you find what you are looking for there. I still think a fresh install is the best way to go.

Comment: Is there any AV software to scan for Trojans to maybe save me having to re-install?

Comment: check for `clamav` in the repositories

Comment: @chris edited my question.

Comment: How can you be sure that viruses don't exist on Ubuntu?

Comment: @andol ok, I can't know, edited, and the risk that it's a virus is very very low...

Comment: Honestly, a fresh install will be a much more comprehensive solution to your problem. You get a lot of assurance for relatively little effort. Copy your important files from your home folder, leaving any executables behind (reinstall these later from trusted sources). An AV scan could miss something or think it's removed the problem when it hasn't.

Comment: OK so I have just run a scan which found 4 infections which I think are false positives.

Comment: @Chris  like I said it's better to make a fresh install.

Comment: I have deleted the files anyway but I think I will resort to reinstalling if the forum admin says it might help. Not sure if I'll get a response from them. To be honest they are being less than helpful and at times quite rude!

Comment: How likely is it that a Trojan would target the Ubuntu forums anyway? It's not like I am a regular user of the forums and I don't think I have any problems elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: @Chris probably as likely it is that you install a trojan.

Comment: -1, Bodhi from the forums has explained what they are doing and why they did it, it's not a trojan or a virus.

Comment: @jrg that was way after I posted my answer, so why the -1?

Comment: @Alvar Because your answer is incorrect. Granted, you acted on the information which you had, but that doesn't change the fact it's a incorrect answer.

Comment: So I really don't get it now. If it's not a virus or a trojan how is a 3rd party using my IP address? I thought you could only have one instance of an IP address on a network, even one as big as the internet. If that's true and I'm connected to the internet with my address how can someone else be using it?

Comment: @Chris you are right, it's confusing, they could have hackad your router. or be connected to the same network as you are.¨

Answer (score 1):

It's far more likely that your account has been hacked in a manner which is nothing to do with your computer. Ask the administrators if they can reset your password for you.